# Pass connection string to custom AuthorizeAttribute in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am migrating `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` from asp.net web api to asp.net core web api.

Below `KeywordAuthorizationAttribute` is in my asp.net core attribute code.

```
public class KeywordAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter 
{

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SQLDataAccess sqlDataAccess = new SQLDataAccess(**passedConnectionStringFrom_appsettings.json**);
            var username = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring
                    (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);


            if (!sqlDataAccess.IsUserAllowed((string)context.RouteData.Values["Controller"], username))
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Example of `KeywordAuthorizationAttribute` - If the controller or controller action is decorated with this AuthorizeAttribute it will take the username and check the access of that controller from database.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[KeywordAuthorization]
public IActionResult Get()

    return Ok();
}
```

My question is how can I pass the connection string to `KeywordAuthorizationAttribute`?
I have already set the connection string in appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EmployeeDBConnection": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=EmployeeDB;Trusted_Connection=true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `AuthorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService` method from the context argument passed into your OnAuthorization method:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    ...

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var connectionString = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetService(typeof(IConfiguration))
            .GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection");
        // GetConnectionString is an extension method, so add
        // using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
               
           ...
    }
}
```

Using this technique, you could also simply use your `DbContext` as well.

Comment: This worked thank you so much, I just had to add one more bracket. ((IConfiguration)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration))).GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConection"); Can you also show how can I do with DbContext?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the extension for Configuration like in Startup.cs and you can get the connection string with:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection");
```